# Expanded usercard not truncated correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, user-card

When I expand my usercard on Super User, I see the following:

[image]

The last link at the bottom is a link to my Google+ profile. The plain-text for which is:

```
• google+: [Oliver Salzburg](https://plus.google.com/+OliverSalzburg)
```

The `google+:` part is replaced by ellipsis in the usercard, but the link is still rendered.

Comment: Seems to happen here too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* kinda weird, especially if you're like me and have a profile summary set up rather than letting the system use the full field, but this is a combination of two things happening:

1. Your "about me" is too long, so it gets truncated.
2. We extract links from the text that didn't make it into the excerpt (either as you define it or as it ends up after truncation) and place them at the bottom of the usercard. For example, here's mine:

[image]

We *should* probably do something a little saner here overall, but at the moment it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

On the upshot, you can (ab)use this to get nicely formatted links at the bottom of your card (`[Google+](https://plus.google.com/+OliverSalzburg)`). :)

Comment: I've just tried to mess with this feature a bit by adding more text to the link. Is this a coincidence that the link text is cut off right after "Oliver Salzburg" or is there some amazing algorithm at play? I changed the text to `Oliver SalzburgHow long can you make this link label before the link is either ignored or truncated as well?` and the result is `Oliver Salzburg…`

Comment: @OliverSalzburg It's a coincidence. The max length is 15 characters, which is exactly what your name works out to.